# How do I query table data only for the current user's ID (VWD asp.net 3.5)?

Tags: c#, database, vb.net, database-design

I'm using the Details View control of VWD asp.net 2008

I have a users database table. One of the columns contain the "uniqueidentifier" user's profile ID, created by VWD (from the automatic profiles table).

From my table, I would like to select only the data pertaining to the logged in user.

How do I get the current unique user profileID in general and then how do I use that for my query?

In the configure data source option of the control, I select the check box for "Return Only Unique IDs" and the WHERE option. In this new window I select the Column to the profile userID ... "=" and then assumed I should select Source: "Profile".

Now what should the parameter properties or value be to select only the current logged userID?

OR how can I do this just in C#?  There doesn't seem to be any code behind after instering a DB with the VWD controls?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/815202-passing-values-sql-datasource

See the last answer from user Munna.